# How to search files at windows folder search that have dash

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, search

I found out that at windows folder search the letter dash `-` works as eliminating the following word from search results.

However I have files that contain dash `-`. How can I search for them them?

For example: I have a file named `my-home.png`

I am using Windows 8.1.

[I found the following documentation](http://www.howtogeek.com/73065/learn-the-advanced-search-operators-in-windows-7/):

Here’s a list of AQS operators that have to do with text searching:

```
NOT/- : Both “not” as well as prefixing a dash will tell your search to exclude items that include the following term.
AND/+ : Both “and” as well as prefixing a plus sign will force your search to only include items that match for both terms.
“” : Using quotes will force a search to filter for an exact phrase.
```

[image]

Answer (score 20):

#### How can I find files in Windows Explorer where the name contains `-`?

The following search expression will match all files that contain a `-` character:

```
~*-*
```

Explanation:

- `~` literal match
- `*` wildcard match
- `-` match the `-`
- `*` wildcard match

So `~*-*` will match all filenames with any characters before a literal `-` and any characters after a literal `-`

You can also `"` the search expression, so

```
"*-*"
```

will also work.

Comment: Is there a reference for how to properly use the windows search box? My god, it drives me absolutely BONKERS trying to figure it out.

Comment: @WayneUroda Read the series starting with [Lesson 1: Stop Hunting and Start Finding!](https://www.howtogeek.com/school/learning-windows-search/lesson1/)

Comment: Better link directly to the article: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/lwef/-search-2x-wds-aqsreference

Comment: I wanted to find all files that I had made a copy of.  So windows will suffix those with a "- Copy" before the extension.  I found that I needed to use the ~ and the quotes to make this work.  And I also made sure it only focused on the name.  So, this worked for me...  name:~"*- Copy*"

Comment: Trying to `"` the search expression has no effect at all, while adding `~` at the beginning does the trick, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Chad good link, but only applies to WDS 2.x which is deprecated. To the people reading this, see Joseph Kingry's answer for the reference doc for WDS 3.x which is current as of 2022-06-22.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem with a file named **hello-world**. So if I tried searching only the word **hello** the file could be found. If I tried searching the word **world** the file is not found. In my search I did not use the **-**. However there seems to be some problem if the filename contains a **-**.

After trying to change indexing options and other complicated stuff the best solution I found was to search with a *.

So for example the search term ***world** finds my file. For now on I will be searching only with the *.

Comment: That should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This answer is great, but windows search is f'ing terrible :/

Answer (score 3):

Here is the reference I finally found for the AQS (Advanced Query Syntax), the default syntax used by `Windows Search`.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-advancedquerysyntax

For example, if I have files like:

```
c:\temp\xyz-abc-001.jpg
c:\temp\xyz-abc-002.jpg
c:\temp\xyz-abc-003.jpg
```

I can use

```
System.FileName:~<"xyz-abc-"
```

Where `~<` is the `COP_VALUE_STARTSWITH` operator.

Comment: This had the benefit of being faster on my super large file count remote shared folder

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem searching for numbers in filenames followed by dash - character
This seems to work

```
~="4000-1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues. At work I have file names such as snstore-surv-nyc-10-mobile.

What works is using the * character to expand the search

Example:

```
snstore*nyc or 
snstore*mobile
```

Unfortunately I haven't found a way of expanding the search to three variables

```
snstore*nyc*mobile
```

Answer (score 0):

Its work for me,

I have a lot of file using dash, i.e: ff-0101-12345, ff-0102-12345, ff-0000-12356

When i tried type in the search bar only 123, that will show nothing in the search result.
It work fine when i type * before word that i will looking for.
Like *123 so it will show search result that match --> 
ff-0101-12345, 
ff-0102-12345, 
ff-0000-12356

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to find filenames containing the hyphenated string, eg "hyphenated-name". I dropped to a command prompt:

```
dir /s "hyphenated-name"
```